# Get posts that match defined arrays of tags

Tags: wp-query, query, tags, query-posts

I've been scratching my head a lot and couldn't find a reasonable solution that would not require multiple queries.

In my case, the posts have multiple tags, but they can be divided into to "sets"

- Platforms (e.g. Facebook, Snapchat)
- Hashtags (e.g. cold, hot, scary)

What I need to fetch are posts that belong to given Platform (can be multiple platforms) and have one of the Hashtags.

Some examples to better explain the needed results.

- Checked tags: **Facebook, cold, hot** - results are posts that have **"cold" and "Facebook"** or **"hot" and "facebook"**
- More complicated: **Facebook, Snapchat, cold, hot** - results are posts that have **"cold" and "Facebook"**, **"cold" and "Snapchat"**, **"hot" and "facebook"**, **"hot" and "snapchat"**.

So basically I need **all the posts for a given platform that have one of the hashtags.**

I do have platforms and hashtags as separate arrays in code, so I can easily distinguish between them, but the problem is that they are all "tags" from Worpdress perspective.

Comment: I would suggest making "Platforms" a separate custom taxonomy. It will make querying the posts much easier: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/working-with-custom-taxonomies/

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the things I was considering, but before updating over 3000 posts I was wondering if it is doable with the data I already have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be achievable with a taxonomy query, like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    [
        'tax_query' => [
            'relation' => 'AND',
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'terms'    => $platforms,
                'compare'  => 'IN',
            ],
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'terms'    => $hashtags,
                'compare'  => 'IN',
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

You just need to substitute the `$platforms` and `$hashtags` variables with the appropriate arrays. If there's a single platform, rather than an array I suggest just using the ID and changing the `'IN'` compare value to `'='` for the first array.

In my comment I said it would be easier to query with a taxonomy, but I realised that's not true, the method would be the same as above. It would however make it easier to manage the terms.

Comment: Just got around to test it out. Worked like a charm. Thanks a million!